# UIBackgroundModes voip doesn't perform properly on Ad-Hoc Builds

Tags: ios

I am creating a Voip/Video application and in debug mode, while in a voip call I can minimize my application and the red bar at the top will appear correctly indicating I am on a call, and enable fast switching back into my app.

However, when i'm attempting this build as an Ad-Hoc build (for testing purposes), this red bar does not appear.

Everything else works as intended, audio still works and I can keep my session open to my server, it's just the damn red bar isn't showing!

Comment: Still haven't figured this one out :(